# CakePHP image upload component

Tags: php, image, network-file-transfer, cakephp

I would like to know how I can improve this CakePHP 3.0 `Component` (inside folder controller)

**1st:** to use external libs (stored on vendor folder) I'm using the `require` keyword and include the class using `use` keyword, like this:

> ```
> require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'CakePHP-ImageTool-Component' . DS . 'ImageTool.php');
> ```

and

> ```
> use ImageTool;
> ```

**2nd:** in method `saveFileLFS` I'm using `true` or `false` to flag OK.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Component;

require_once(ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'CakePHP-ImageTool-Component' . DS . 'ImageTool.php');

use Burzum\FileStorage\Lib\StorageManager;
use Cake\Controller\Component;
use ImageTool;

class UploadFileComponent extends Component
{
    function resizeImage($settings)
    {
        $status = ImageTool::resize([
            'input' => $settings['input'],
            'output' => $settings['output'],
            'width' => $settings['width'],
            'height' => $settings['height'],
            'mode' => $settings['mode']
        ]);
        return $status;
    }

    public function saveFileLFS($stringSeparator, $storeName, $productName)
    {
        $key = $storeName . $stringSeparator . $productName . $stringSeparator .
            $this->request->data['Media']['file']['name'];
        if(StorageManager::adapter('Local')->write($key,
            file_get_contents($this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name']))){
            return true;
        }else
       {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Good job on your first question.

Comment: @SirPython thank you, I'm originally user from pt.stackoverflow

Comment: You may find this a useful read [Uploading files and images with CakePHP 3](http://josediazgonzalez.com/2015/12/04/uploading-files-and-images/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **If you have another point to improve, please comment or answer, I will change the accepted answer**

To change the `require` I use the `composer.json` `classmap` like this (follow this answer: [Import Class without autoload and repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090241/import-vendor-class-in-cakephp-3-without-require)):

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "./vendor/CakePHP-ImageTool-Component"
    ]
}
```

I don't use `require` now.

In `saveFileLFS` method now I'm using `Exception` if something don't work.

```
public function saveFileLFS($stringSeparator, $storeName, $productName)
{
    $key = $storeName . $stringSeparator . $productName . $stringSeparator .
        $this->request->data['Media']['file']['name'];
    if(!StorageManager::adapter('Local')->write($key,
        file_get_contents($this->request->data['Media']['file']['tmp_name']))){
        throw new MissingHelperException();
        //Or other Exception
    }
}
```